# How to use result of sql query/queries for another select query?

Tags: mysql, select-query

```
SELECT *
FROM emp e LEFT OUTER JOIN dep d ON
e.Dno=d.Dno

UNION
SELECT *
FROM emp e RIGHT OUTER JOIN dep d ON
e.Dno=d.Dno
```

I want to use the result coming from this to another select query. How can I do that?

I only have emp and dep tables.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for subqueries. http://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php